# 301 Redirect Mod-Rewrite (directory to individual file)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Google indexed a website that I replaced. I want to forward an existing url structure but I am having two problems.

1) I am trying to redirect http://www.abc.com/testimonials/ to http://www.abc.com/testimonials.html and it doesn't work. Here is what happens.

a) With WWW,  nothing happens.
b) Without WWW, it redirects to to testimonials.html/ but with the trailing slash

Here is code I have in htaccess file

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$
rewriterule ^testimonials$ "http\:\/\/abc\.com\/testimonials\.html" [R=301,L]
```

Any advice to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^/testimonials/$ http://abc.com/testimonials.html [R=301,L]
```

If you don't want to delete "www" from a site name, try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^/testimonials/$ /testimonials.html [R=301,L]
```

There are good examples how to use mod_rewrite:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: still goes to testimonials.html/ actually. Only other code I have in there is this:

`code`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.(html?|php|asp|cfm)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html?|php|asp|cfm)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

and

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]`code`

Comment: What are they doing? Are they redirecting requests to abc.com folder (not site)? If you want redirect to site you should add "http://" before site name. And even in this situation your last RewriteRule will always redirect to the same place. I changed code in answer a bit and don't forget to restart apache.